# Should I fetch all objects initially or when each view controller is loaded?

Tags: iphone, ios, coding-style

thanks right away. This is my first question and am excited to join the iOS developer community. I have one core data entity (say, a car). I have a tab view controller with two tabs - one displaying all cars and another displaying all types of cars (Chevy, Ford, etc.). The question deals with this second view controller. My question is - do I want to fetch all of my cars when the tab is loaded then pass all relevant cars of that type when the row is selected, or do I want to fetch my results after a row is selected meaning I'd have a different view controller for each type of car?

UPDATE:
I do, indeed, have two table views. The second one with the types has a list of types. When a row is selected I'm curious if I should pass the relevant cars to this VC or fetch the results?

Comment: You might wanna look at your Q@A again. Don't forget to accept and/or upvote answers that were usefull to you! And good luck in this iOS community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you use 2 ViewControllers: 1 for all the Cars and then 1 for all the relevant cars of that type. You can just pass the relevant data (let's say an array of carmodels) from the FirstVC (where you put your initial array of cars *, or dictionary if you will*) to the secondVC and adjust your VC-looks accordingly.

*(Seems you want to work with a UITableView to do this, it is very simple to pass these kind of messages through to a new VC and do the customization you want anyway)*

---

You will all find your UITableView answers right here in the AppleDoc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

A UITableView object must have an object that acts as a data source and an object that acts as a delegate; typically these objects are either the application delegate or, more frequently, a custom UITableViewController object. The data source must adopt the UITableViewDataSource protocol and the delegate must adopt the UITableViewDelegate protocol. The data source provides information that UITableView needs to construct tables and manages the data model when rows of a table are inserted, deleted, or reordered. The delegate provides the cells used by tables and performs other tasks, such as managing accessory views and selections.

One of these delegate methods you seek is the

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

This method will trigger when you select a row in your tableView. In this method you want to call and show your new VC and this is also when you pass the relevant data to that new VC. The rest of the above will still hold up then.

Good luck.